# What battle/battles were the Separatist leaders viewing inside the Mustafar war room?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

Just wondering as to what was the battle that Nute Gunray and the other Separatist leaders were viewing inside the Mustafar war room as Darth Vader was near.
I saw AT-APs on the table so I am guessing it was perhaps Kashyyyk, but I'm not too sure.

Comment: I just checked the novelization. No specific clues are given - the fact is that by the time Anakin arrives, it's been an hour since they shut down the droid armies.

Comment: @DVK I thought Vader deactivated them on Mustafar after he assassinated the Separatist Council.

Comment: @null that differs between movie and novelization.

Comment: It could also have been a recording from a previous battle. It didn't necessarily have to be a live feed. Or maybe 'live', but time delayed due to the distance involved?

Answer (score 7):

## Analysis from the Episode III film only

For reference here is the highest quality clip of the Separatist Council assassination I could find on Youtube:

You are correct that the walkers are [AT-APs](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/All_Terrain_Attack_Pod). The walkers are the only distinguishing features of the battle(s) so it is impossible to identify the battle based on terrain (although the *lack* of visible terrain may itself be a clue). Unfortunately, the film does not clearly identify which battles continued until the deactivation of the Separatist droid armies (the event which coincides with the Separatist Council assassination in the film). The best indication given by Episode III is based on which battles were ongoing when Order 66 was given, since Order 66 was given shortly before Vader was sent to Mustafar to assassinate the Separatist Council and deactivate the droid armies. Even then, not all battles fought during Order 66 were necessarily shown in Episode III. It is also possible that there is a time delay between the actual battle(s) and the recordings; however, the Separatists would presumably view the battles as close to real time as possible and the film gives us no clue what time delay (if any) there is, so we have to assume they were watching the battles that were raging around the time when Order 66 was given.

For reference here is a clip of the clones carrying out Order 66:

We see the following:

- [Attempted assassination of Obi-Wan Kenobi on Utapau](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Utapau/Canon)
- [Assassination of Ki-Adi Mundi on Mygeeto](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ki-Adi-Mundi/Canon#Execution_on_Mygeeto)
- [Assassination of Aayla Secura on Felucia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aayla_Secura/Canon)
- [Assassination of Plo Koon over Cato Neimoidia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Plo_Koon/Canon)
- [Assassination of Stass Allie on Saleucami](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Stass_Allie/Canon)
- [Attempted assassination of Yoda at the Battle of Kashyyyk](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda/Canon#Order_66)

The Battle of Utapau seems to have continued until the deactivation of the droid army, but Utapau's sinkhole cities are not conducive to walkers (at least not in motion as seen by the Separatists). AT-APs very likely participated in the Battles of Mygeeto and Felucia (other walkers are seen) but neither planet has particularly open terrain so some terrain should have been visible to the Separatists on Mustafar (but perhaps the terrain was filtered out). We don't see the ground battle in the Battle of Cato Neimoidia so we can't confirm from the film that AT-APs participated in the battle and therefore we can't tell if the Separatists may have been watching it. The fighting on Saleucami was largely over by the time Order 66 was given ([Obi-Wan declared that Saleucami had "fallen"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Outer_Rim_Sieges#Victory_for_the_Republic) earlier in the film) and there didn't appear to be an ongoing battle when Stass Allie was killed, so the Separatists were probably not watching a battle on Saleucami. The Battle of Kashyyyk was ongoing during Order 66 and an AT-AP can be seen in the film so it is a good possibility that the Separatists were watching this battle, especially since the battle was fought largely over an open beachhead (explaining the apparent lack of terrain features).

The evidence from the film therefore indicates that **the Separatists were watching the Battle of Kashyyyk, possibly the Battle of Mygeeto and/or the Battle of Felucia, and possibly (though least likely) the Battle of Utapau**.

## Analysis including Legends

The AT-AP participated in the [Outer Rim Sieges](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Outer_Rim_Sieges), which included the following battles:

- Siege of Saleucami
- Battle of Boz Pity
- Battle of Felucia
- Battle of Belderone
- Battle of Mygeeto
- Battle of Utapau

The [Wookieepedia AT-AP article](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/All_Terrain_Attack_Pod#The_Clone_Wars) specifically mentions their use in the Battle of Kashyyyk and Felucia, but does not mention their use in Mygeeto or Utapau. They are not listed in the Legends article for the [Battle of Utapau](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Utapau) but they *are* included in the list of Republic forces for the [Battle of Mygeeto](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Mygeeto_%28Clone_Wars%29).

Two additional battles which did not appear in the film were part of the Outer Rim Sieges: the Battle of Boz Pity was largely over by the time of Order 66 ([the 
Republic had won and the Separatists had evacuated](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Boz_Pity#The_Clone_Wars)), and the [Battle of Belderone](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Belderone) was already over and was a Republic victory.

The AT-AP also participated in the [Battle of Cato Neimoidia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Cato_Neimoidia_%28Order_66%29). It is a distinct possibility that the Separatist Council was monitoring this battle since it took place in Nute Gunray's home system.

A number of other minor battles were fought concurrently, but the Separatist Council was probably watching only the most significant battle(s).

Consequently, when including Legends evidence, **the Separatists may have been watching the Battle of Kashyyyk, Battle of Mygeeto, Battle of Felucia, and/or Battle of Cato Neimoidia**.